# Как в sharepoint получить сам текст критической (неожиданной) ошибки?

Tags: sharepoint

После переустановки SharePoint 2007 v12.0 поднял практически все страницы.
Не могу понять по какой причине, на некоторых страницах закономерно  появляется такая (ниже) unexpected error. Ошибку выдаёт сервер после post-запроса (иногда на некоторых страницах сразу при входе при get-запросе). Страницы - обычные aspx + dwp-sharepoint-плагины.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я уже перепробовал всё что знал:

- В Central administration http://localhost:3442/_admin/metrics.aspx вроде поставил все галочки, пересмотрел все логи из папки `Trace Log` C:\program files\common files\Microshft shared\Web server extensions\12\LOGS
- Повключал везде где нашёл `<customErrors mode="Off" />` web.config и *.config всех конфигов на машине
- Искал ошибки в EventLog винды

но получить более вменяемый текст ошибки не удаётся.
Я догадывался что проблема с Ajax, теперь точно скажу что ajax.
Когда в ajax компоненте (dropdownlist) выбираете значение, то выходит вот такая ошибка

> Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. --->
>   System.ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument. Event
>   validation is enabled using in configuration or <%@ Page
>   EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page. For security purposes, this
>   feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events
>   originate from the server control that originally rendered them. If
>   the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation. at
>   System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent(String uniqueId,
>   String argument) at System.Web.UI.Control.ValidateEvent(String
>   uniqueID, String eventArgument) at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList.LoadPostData(String
>   postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList.System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.LoadPostData(String
>   postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData,
>   Boolean fBeforeLoad) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e) at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) at
>   ASP.page_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in
>   c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\91959b08\8d1b1582\App_Web_page.aspx.cdcab7d2.mqhgfyw4.0.cs:line
>   0 at HTTPHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in
>   c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\virtualdirectories\80540dd3fa-b4b0-4a89-911e-544097461230\App_Code\HTTPHandler.cs:line
>   136

Настройки ajax перепроверил, но пока не нашёл в чём проблема.

Comment: Какие ошибки попадают в логи SP?

Comment: Логов много. Выкладывать все нет смысла, OWSTimer много событий, но слов PZList в логах нету, и новое событие после ошибки не появляется в логах. Вот это странно.

Comment: А что не нравится службе таймера? Есть какие то экшны связанные с этой страницей и службой таймера?

Comment: Связь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45465622/how-get-details-of-unexpected-sharepoint-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл таки "обработчик" ошибок. Любые ошибки непрошедшие try..catch приводили к этому окошку (ведь обрабатывает dwp сначала sharepoint). Что б оключить это "окно" ошибки, нужно в `Web.Config` найти `SafeMode` и поменять `False` (по умолчанию) на `True` как ниже:

```
<configuration>
<SharePoint>
   <SafeMode MaxControls="200" CallStack="True" DirectFileDependencies="10" 
    TotalFileDependencies="50" AllowPageLevelTrace="True">
```

Так же нужно выставить `<customErrors mode="Off" />` и `<compilation debug="true">` (это уже для ASP NET)

Дополнительно информация https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231550.aspx